# In Cakephp using a helper to set template variables

Tags: php, cakephp, helper

Is it possible to set a template variable in a helper?

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is have a helper add in code to the header of the layout, for use with javascript and such.

Ways I can think of that I'd prefer not to use:

- Passing in the view object: don't want to worry about having to call an extra function
- using the "global" keyword to get the view, I really like to avoid using this except as a last resort since it's not considered orthodox

Any thoughts?

**Update 2012-02-20:**
As cake as been updated more recently I've tried to include answers to Cake 1.2 as well as Cake 2. Thanks to Adam and mark for their recommendations

Comment: You should always note which cakephp version you are using!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered you can use the class registry to grab it, so I made this function in my helper:

```
/**
 * Access to the view for special operatoins
 */
protected function getView() {
    return ClassRegistry::getObject('view');
}
```

Update 2013-02-20:
I wrote the above for Cake 1.2, Adam (in the comment below) suggested using `$this->_View->viewVars['var']` for Cake 2.3 which looks good, but I don't have a way to test.

Comment: Might not work in latest cake...  However:  `$this->_View->viewVars['var']`  in helper does the trick in cake2.3 (courtesy of @atomicguava )

Comment: True, I believe I wrote this for cake 1.2. I'll add in your comments to this answer